# What is the font used in the Rio All-Suite Hotel & Casino logo?

Tags: font-identification

I think this is a vector logo with a modified font. I cannot find anything close to it using the popular font-identifying services (whatthefont, dafont, myfonts, identifont, etc.).  Please note that this is a non-free logo and all rights belong to the owner.

[Rio Logo as found on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Rio_Vegas_logo.svg)

[image]

Comment: Looks like someone just wrote it with a marker and then vectorized it.

Answer (score 1):

There are marker and "sharpie" type fonts, but I agree that the Rio one is probably custom, either scanned or directly drawn as vector art.

Comment: This logo has been around a long time. Chances are it was created by hand by a branding agency. There's no lack of funding behind that one ;-)